# Tokenize multiple sentences to rows in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I have a text dataframe like this,

```
id      text
1       Thanks.  I appreciate your help.  I really like this chat service as it is very convenient.  I hope you have a wonderful day! thanks!
2       Got it. Thanks for the help; good nite.
```

I want to split those text sentences and match them to each id. My expected output is,

```
id      text
1       Thanks.
1       I appreciate your help.
1       I really like this chat service as it is very convenient.
1       I hope you have a wonderful day!
1       thanks!
2       Got it.
2       Thanks for the help;
2       good nite.
```

Is there any nltk functions that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1st `split` then use `explode` , if you are not upgrade your `pandas` to 0.25 , check [How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
df.assign(text=df.text.str.split('[.!;]')).explode('text').loc[lambda x : x.text!='']
Out[181]: 
                                                text  id
0                                             Thanks   1
0                             I appreciate your help   1
0    I really like this chat service as it is ver...   1
0                    I hope you have a wonderful day   1
0                                             thanks   1
1                                             Got it   2
1                                Thanks for the help   2
1                                          good nite   2
```